# Sharing Sessions Between Stores with Different Domains

Tags: multistore, session, cookie

I have three websites on a Magento installation, each has its own domain.

Now due to web-browser security you cannot access cookies from another domain, nor sessions.

Somehow I need to be able to pass temporary data between two different stores with different domains.

*My specific use case:*

I am using GeoIP to trigger a redirect to the correct countries store, however I also need to be able to manually override this. Now at the moment I am having the issue where I am manually overriding on the current store with a cookie, however when I am redirected to the other store, there is no cookie on the other store, so it falls back and looks up the users store based on GeoIP. However this then creates an infinity loop redirecting between too stores.

This is done by figuring out the website code for the store I want to use in `index.php` with a custom module and running Magento with the correct code. This handles all redirects etc for me then.

Comment: Are your store views placed in different websites? I mean websites in the terminology of Magento. If yes, you may also need to read this article, that explains, how to create a simple extension, that shares the shopping cart between different Magento websites: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2013/01/share-cart-between-websites.html?spref=tw

Answer (score 5):

You can share `frontend` cookie between magento website with different domains using that solution [ainixon.me/set-cookie-on-cross-domains](http://www.ainixon.me/set-cookie-on-cross-domains/).

You need to create `cookies.php` file with the following code

```
<?php
    setcookie("frontend", htmlspecialchars($_GET['SID']), time() + 86400);
?>
```

and in magento template you will need to add following code after the `<body>` tag

```
<?php 
$this_session_id = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->getSessionId(); 
?>
<!-- setting cookies to other domains --> 
<img src="http://anotherdomain.com/cookies.php?SID=<?php echo $this_session_id; ?>" style="display:none;" />
<img src="http://somedomain.ne/cookies.php?SID=<?php echo $this_session_id; ?>" style="display:none;" /> 
<!-- setting cookies to others domains ends -->
```

Comment: Hi your solution awesome. But i'm a little confused about the magento 2.1.3 version. so where should i enter this code in this new version?

Comment: Some security implications of this suggestion were discussed here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174678/is-this-an-insecure-implementation-of-multi-site-sessions/174720#174720

Answer (score 3):

Just redirect with `?SID=yourSessionId` then you can just use it on the other store view.

Comment: Magento doesn't have a configuration to enable or not the SID in the urls? I think there is something in Configuration > Web > Session. No?

Comment: yes, when you redirect between storeviews. there is something, but I don't think this works if you do it manually. But yes Luke, have a look into this in the backend and the consequensted, might make the life easier :)

Comment: This is already enabled, but I does not work for me by default. The module we created is designed to pull a location based on IP and then direct accordingly, and also allow people to select stores. I am simply working out the mage_run_code before Mage::run is initially called.

But I do not know how I can add a custom session value before mage run and also have the session id appended to the url redirect, as this is handled in core/url

Comment: just search the code for SID. Everything happens here: `\Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract::setSessionId()` so just check when the session id is set and set it.

Comment: The issue here being that I am calling this before Mage::run so i cannot set anything at this point from what I can tell.  

`Mage::init();
list( $mageRunCode, $mageRunType ) = Mage::helper('director')->run( $mageRunCode, $mageRunType );

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);``

Comment: the session handling is started later, so you don't have to do it soo early. Just add the SID to your url when passing it from one to the other store and check wether it is used, if not, check why

Comment: You might want to be more specific when suggesting this. If the SID is appended to a URL available from a link, the user could share that link on a forum or elsewhere which would cause you all sorts of problems.

Comment: @pspahn, if you have better approach please suggest. I think that's working approach and I don't see other way to achieve the task for magento with multiple different domains.

Comment: finally I found better solution, you can share frontend cookie between magento website with different domains using that solution http://www.ainixon.me/set-cookie-on-cross-domains/

Comment: @electroid you should add this as an answer! It is great and valuable!

Answer (score 2):

Just ensure `Use SID in frontend` is enabled.

Any ...

- URL generated by `Mage::getUrl()`
- Redirect with `$this->_redirectUrl($url);` or `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect()`

Will then contain the respect `SID`.

If you are using `files` for session storage, just make sure the directory is commonly `symlinked`; if you are using Memcache/Redis/DB, this isn't a concern.

--

Just note, there is a lot of graceful ways to handle GeoIP redirection further up than Magento. You could do it at the webserver level (checking the presence of your respective "no-redirect" cookie).

Comment: I have found that it is including the SID on the end of the URL initially but it keeps redirecting around in circles. What I want to do is when I manually redirect set a session value to stop it looking up the IP again next time to send it back to where it came from. However I get an error like "Mage registry key "controller" already exists" when ever I try to access any factory methods in magento or retrieve session data  etc. So I am trying to find a way to pass a flag to say "no don't lookup again please". Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have a redirect loop just because of your own code. There's no real way I can help you on here, your issue is far too localised.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin, go to Configuration > Web > Session > Use SID on Frontend and enable.

When going from one site to another, pass the session by including this in the url (use `&` if you already use `?` for a `$_GET` parameter)

```
?SID=<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->getSessionId(); ?>
```