# How to share cart for guest users between multi stores with different domain

Tags: multistore, addtocart, shopping-cart, guest-checkout

I am able to share my cart for logged in customers while switching between two stores with different domain URLs. However, I could not implement the same for guest users. I know the `cart details` are saving into the `quote` table. But this is not shared with the second store while switching.

Please guide me to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to solve this issue by sharing the session cookie between the stores. I have followed this answer. I manually creates the same cookie in my two domains so that data will be shared between the two.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3624/49598

Comment: can you tell me what do you did exactly to share the `cart` between two stores? i have add `SID` in the url like `url?SID=session_id` and enabled `SID` in admin and set `Cookie Path = /`, `Cookie Domain = .example.com`, but still not working any steps missing?

Comment: @mahmoudismail: plz check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/132654